# How do you check the success of open (file) in Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io

The following (not very Perl-ish) code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if (! -e "mydir/")
{
  print "directory doesn't exist.\n";
}
open (my $fh, ">", "mydir/file.txt");
if ($fh)
{
  print "file opened.\n";
  print $fh;
  print $fh "some text\n" or die "failed to write to file.\n";
  close ($fh);
}
else
{
  print "failed to open file.\n";
}
```

produces the output such as this

```
directory doesn't exist.
file opened.
failed to write to file.
GLOB(0x...some-hex-digits...)
```

Why is *$fh* not equivalent to false following the open call?
As *mydir/* does not exist, I'd expect the attempt to open the file to fail.

I get similar results if the directory and file exist, but the file is read-only.

I've tried this with Perl 5.10.1 on Windows 7 x64, and with Perl 5.10.0 on Fedora-11 Linux.

I'm guessing my file handle test is wrong.
I've tried Googling this without luck.
I expect it's something obvious, but any hints or links would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Rob.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`$fh` isn't being set to a zero-ish value, it is being set to a `GLOB` as your code shows. This is different from what `open` returns which is why the idiom is

```
open(...) or die ... ;
```

or

```
unless(open(...)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 20):

`open` returns a non-zero value on success, and a "false" value on failure. The idiom you are looking for is

```
if (open my $fh, '>', $file) {
    # open was successful
} else {
    # open failed - handle error
}
```

If the first argument (`$fh`) is undefined (as it is in this case), `open` will initialize it to some arbitrary value (see the [`Symbol::genysm` method](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Symbol)) *before* it attempts to open the file. So `$fh` will **always** be "true" even if the `open` call fails.

Comment: The other nice thing about this pattern is that you do not need to `close $fh;` because it is automatically done at the end of the `if` block when `$fh` goes out of scope.  There is more detail at this Perlmonks post: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=376754

Answer (score 9):

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> Open returns nonzero on success, the undefined value otherwise.

An often used idiom is

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die $!;
```

Of course you can do something else than simply `die`.

Comment: Additional tip: use `perldoc -f open` to get help on a Perl built-in function.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the explanations in the other answers:

Check out the [autodie](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie) module which comes with perl 5.10.1 and up (and is available separately from CPAN).

Answer (score 0):

Just a warning

```
unless (open my $fh , '<', 'foobar') {
    print "Error Opening";
}
print $fh, "Some Text";
```

will fail, as `$fh` is defined in `unless` context, not outside/after it.
So only the if contruct from above will work.