# Perl : Not able to point at the starting using seek function?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I tried this code.

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Fcntl qw(SEEK_SET SEEK_CUR SEEK_END);

open($file1) # I didn't put full line
open (F_log)

while (my $line = <$file1>) {
    my @fields = split " ", $line;
    my $length = @fields;

    for (my $i=3; $i<5 ;$i+="1") {
        $i_d = $fields[$i];

        last if ($.==1);

        seek F_log, 0, SEEK_SET; # not working
            while(my $LINE = (<F_log>)) { 
                if ($. >= $a ) {
                    if ($LINE =~ /^\s+(\w+)\s\s"(\w+)",/) { 
                    if ($1 eq $i_d) {
                        $fields[$i] = $2;
                        last;   
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        $fields[$i] = "Error:$i_d";

                    };
                };
            };  
        }; 
    };
}
close
close
```

I want to read whole `<F_log>` everytime their increment in loop. I tried other method of opening/closing file inside while loop and it works but I think that will increase run time memory of script(Not Sure). So now I am  trying to reset the pointer to starting but it's not working. Can anyone suggest anything? And also if anyone tell what all things increases the run time memory of script. Thankyou

Comment: What error do you get? (`seek(F_log,0,SEEK_SET) or die("seek: $!\n");`)

Comment: It's likely `open (F_log)` didn't work. You need to check if all your file functions worked. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203860/how-do-you-check-the-success-of-open-file-in-perl

Comment: Your code does not compile. Could you post a [more complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the actual error might be the use of `$.` as the line number. There's no way to know for `seek` to know into which line you seeked, so `seek` doesn't change `$.`. It just keeps going up.

In this particular use of `seek`, you know you're back before the first line. Try using `$. = 0;` after the seek.

---

Demonstration

`a.pl`:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl qw( SEEK_SET );

open(my $fh, "<", "a.txt") or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
   print "$.: $_";
}

seek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET) or die $!;
$. = 0 if $ARGV[0];

while (<$fh>) {
   print "$.: $_";
}
```

`a.txt`:

```
a
b
c
```

Output:

```
$ perl a.pl 0
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: a
5: b
6: c

$ perl a.pl 1
1: a
2: b
3: c
1: a
2: b
3: c
```

Comment: but we write `seek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET)` this should set the pointer to starting then why we to $.=0? I didn't understand this.

Comment: Also I my code I am reading two files using while loop one inside the another So if I write `$.=0` after seek why/how it is changing the pointer for `<F_log>` and not for `<file1>`?

Comment: There's no point in having `seek` set `$.` for one very specific set of inputs and no others. That would be the more confusing interface.

Comment: From perlvar, "When a line is read from a filehandle (via `readline()` or `<>`), or when `tell()` or `seek()` is called on it, `$.` becomes an alias to the line counter for that filehandle." So if you seek, `$.` becomes an alias for the handle passed to `seek`, so assigning to `$.` will affects that handle's line counter.